# Passing around an NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

My Core Data stack is set up in the AppDelegate as usual. I am a good OO citizen and recognize that accessing it directly via `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]` (or moving it to some singleton) is global state/code smell/naughty.

But the controller that needs to access the data is about five layers deep. There are container controllers and modals and bears in between. Am I supposed to pass the context down through each layer simply so that the last screen can spit out a list of entities? Seems like this restricts reusability, increases complexity, and decreases understandability.

Comment: If the controller that needs the data is five layers deep, is it a part of an hierarchical controller structure - that is - do the controllers inherit from a "parent" and at the top from a "root" controller? If so you may be able to set a public MOC for that "root" controller, based on the AppDelegate MOC, which then by default is inherited by all "child" controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are supposed to pass it around as per Apples recommendations. However I have been lazy in some circumstances and just grabbed it off the App delegate because I'm not doing anything multi-threaded computing. I try most of the time to stick to Apples guideliness and make sure I pass the context around by default so If I ever need it lower I have it.

"A view controller typically shouldn’t retrieve the context from a global object such as the application delegate—this makes the application architecture rigid."

Check out the iOS info that apple recommends https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord), it provides lots of convenience methods for all kinds of Core Data typical usage cases.

With it, you don't need to manually keep track of your context, the convenience methods automatically access it (them) in a thread safe way.

It also suports background model saving and less boilerplatery fetching.

Comment: Some Magical Record hater downvoting around. :D